# Complex Event Processing

Tags: java, event-handling, design-patterns

Need a bit of advise on designing a event processing system.
On a high level, my Java server receives a variety of requests, executes and responds (synchronously and asynchronously) to them.

The flow is as follows:

a) A low level class receives the event from a client. This class has a reference to a MessageRouter class. Once it gets the event, it simply calls route( Event event ) on MessageRouter.

b) MessageRouter class queues the events and in a separate thread, determines the type of the message, finds the appropriate Handler and hands the message off to it.

c) Handler executes the message.

d) ResponseRouter gathers the response and writes it back.

My questions are:

1) How should I design c) as I need references to 4-5 other "Manager" sort of classes to execute the request. Also, should c) have a reference to d) to route the response back?

2) Similarly, d) needs references to other classes to write back the responses as they can be done synchronously and asynchronously . Should ResponseRouter have a reference to all the classes it needs?

Mainly, I am looking for a design pattern (or a combination of them) to lay the execution of the events and their responses in an efficient and elegant manner.

Comment: i don't fully understand those 'Manager' classes...more Handlers? for example the IORecievers are some kind of http gates async/sync; and handler1 loads the data into the object, handler2 does some business logic handler3 writes back data into store, handler4 creates response html etc?

Comment: Mediator pattern should solve the problem. I don't know much about java, but C# implementation of the pattern handles both sync and async messaging

Answer (score 0):

As for an answer to Q2 since handlers can be executed async i would suggest handleing request and response would be more straightforward done in the MessageRouter perhaps with references to 2 other objects implementing an RequestRouter and ResponseRouter interface.

When the handler has complete it could give its result back to the MessageRouter either in a sync or async manner.

This way handlers do not need a reference to the ResponseRouter.